# WebStorm with git doesn't recognize renamed folders

Tags: git, rename, webstorm, directory

Each time that I rename a folder WebStorm and I press `Ctrl+k` to view the files changed, WebStorm doesn't recognize. If I go to Terminal and I press `$ git status` git shows me that changes.

How I can configure WebStorm to view and commit those folders?

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm does this by default. Within `git` you are working against a filepath as there is no concept of a folder. An example `git` output for a modified file, both before and after are shown below:

```
 $ git status
 M bin/app.pl
 $ git status
 R  bin/app.pl -> bin2/app.pl
 R  bin/compiler.pl -> bin2/compiler.pl
```

As you can see `git` does not display a folder name change. It shows filepath changes because again, *Git doesn't track directories; but just the files within them.*

During a commit with the WebStorm VCS as `git` you DO see the files as shown in the second example `git status` above and the files will be notated in the Commit Changes dialog with "- moved from ../bin/"